# Text alignment in minipage with tikzpicture

Tags: minipage, baseline

Using 3 minipages, while in the second one is a tikz, will produce the text part not aligned to each other (see red line).

[image]

Is there o solution without vspace/tabular/multicols etc. to align the baseline of the text?
More specific: Can I force the text after tikzpicture to start at the same baseline as the others?

Here is the code:

```
\begin{minipage}[t]{50mm}
Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test
\end{minipage}\hspace*{8mm}\begin{minipage}[t]{50mm}
Test Test Test Test Test Test

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0)--(5,2.9);
\end{tikzpicture}

Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test
\end{minipage}\hspace*{8mm}\begin{minipage}[t]{50mm}
Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test
\end{minipage}
```

Comment: In central `minipage` put less vertical space for picture and/or for text.

Comment: The middle mini page is taller than others. Do you mean *the second one contains a TikZ* or *the second one is a `tikzpicture`*?

Comment: One might adjust the `tikzpicture` so that it covers integer factors of number of lines but this will fail quick when there's other non-text content in either one of the minipages (say a display math environment).

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel thats a good idea. I will try this approach. Thx a lot!

Comment: @Sigur as in the sample, I used tikzpicture. My mistake...

Comment: The other problem is that sometime interline distance is greater than the baseline skip, for example for large symbols... There is a method to "fix" interline skip but I can't find the Q&A here... But using insets only with vertical sizes multiple of baselineskip is the only option, I think.

Comment: @Rmano I guess i have to make some boxes which im gonna define the vertical space (multiple times baselineskip) and put the tikzpicture (or different things) inside it. Then after the box with a new line, im should land exactly at the same baseline each time.